# How do I help the farmer?

Tags: terminus

I'm playing [Terminus](http://mprat.github.io/Terminus/Web/main.html).

I just `rm`-ed the huge boulder out of my path, so now I have access to the farm:

```
>cd Farm
You have moved to Farm. There was once a farm of some sort here, but now the 
fields are scorched and brown. 
>ls
 Locations: 

 Items: 
EarOfCorn
Farmer
```

Okay...what do I do here?

```
>less EarOfCorn
The corn is sad and withered-looking.
```

Not helpful.

```
>less Farmer
"Ruined! I'm ruined! Look at these crops... almost nothing left! The wizard's 
minions were here last week... they destroyed everything. How will I feed my 
3 children with just one ear of corn? I could really use AnotherEarOfCorn! "
```

I know! I'll use the `mkdir` spell I learned back in the library:

```
>mkdir AnotherEarOfCorn
Command 'mkdir' not found in room 'Farm'
```

Uh oh...

```
>help 
Type 'man' to ask the man for help
>man mkdir 
there is no man page for that command
```

How can I help the poor farmer?

Comment: i dunno, try mounting him? ;)

Comment: @spartacus Sadly, that command isn't found, either :P

Comment: I haven't actually played the game but this sounds like a situation where I would try to make a COPY of the corn, rather than a new object that happens to be named corn. Do you have access to some kind of cp EarOfCorn AnotherEarOfCorn command?

Comment: @Lawton Make that an answer, and I'll edit into it the farmer's words of gratitude :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't actually played the game but this sounds like a situation where I would try to make a COPY of the corn, rather than a new object that happens to be named corn. Turns out this was in fact the right answer.

```
>cp EarOfCorn AnotherEarOfCorn
Just copied EarOfCorn into AnotherEarOfCorn.

>less Farmer
It’s a miracle! Thank you, friend. May the Admin bless you.
```

Comment: Ah, turns out you officially learn this spell in the `ArtisanShop`, which is a shop in the `TownSquare` I hadn't visited yet.